# append HTML tags to output function result in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

What I need is to show the output of a function in a h1 tag. I have problems with the quotes. Thanks.

```
$("#pTempActual").append("<h1>"'_datosClima.main.temp+"ºC"'"</h1>");
```

_datosClima.main.temp is the variable that holds the result, you can take it as a number for the purpose of the question. ºC is a string.

PD: I need to do it this way, without creating new functions to change that output to string, h, p, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Element.insertAdjacentHTML()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)
 that parses the specified text as HTML or XML and inserts the resulting nodes into the DOM tree at a specified position.

And

[Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) that allows embedded expressions:

```js
var _datosClima = {main: {}};
_datosClima.main.temp = 33;

document.getElementById("pTempActual").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<h1>${_datosClima.main.temp}ºC</h1>`);
```

```html
<p id="pTempActual"></p>
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, but how could I do it without that library?